# $\sqrt[n]{2^k}$ is irrational for $k=1,2,...,n-1$

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

We all know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. We can use the same proof to show that $n \in \mathbb{N}: \sqrt[n]{2}$ is also irrational.

But how to show that

$$
\sqrt[n]{2^k} \quad \text{is irrational for} \; k = 1, 2, ..., n-1
$$

?

Comment: Write out the proof that $\sqrt[n]2$ is irrational.  Then see what happens if you replace $2$ with $2^k$.  (Hint:  If $k\le n-1$, then $1\le n-k$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\sqrt[n]{2^k} = \dfrac{a}{b}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. Then $a^n = 2^k b^n$.

Write $a=2^\alpha a'$ and $b=2^\beta b'$, with $a',b'$ odd.

Then $n \alpha = k + n \beta$ and so $k$ is a multiple of $n$. Since $ 0 < k < n$, this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

For another proof, note that $x^n-2 \in \mathbb Q[x]$ is irreducible by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion).

Actually this shows that $1,\sqrt[n]{2}, \dotsc, \sqrt[n]{2^{n-1}}$ are $\mathbb Q$-linear independent, which is an even stronger result.

Comment: Thx, unfortunaly this does not help me as the actual problem, I want to solve is exactly that $x^n-2$ is irreducible. (And I do not know about Eisenstein's criterion yet).

Comment: And I precisely showed you how to proof that. So how on earth does this *not* help? Furthermore, as I pointed out: The irreducibility of those numbers is much weaker than the irreducibility of $x^n-2$.

Comment: If you do not know Eisensteins' criterion, you could just hard copy its (very easy) proof to show that $x^n-2$ is irreducible.

Comment: Here is an elementary proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822675/showing-that-xn-2-is-irreducible-in-mathbbqx